# How to list all commands in a package?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packages

I just downloaded the w3c-markup-validator package from the universe repositories, but I can't seem to figure out how to run it. How can I list the new commands available?

Comment: I don't have privs to retag yet, but can you add Aptitude please?

Answer (score 3):

`dpkg -L w3c-markup-validator` lists all the files in the package. You want the executables in the path, so

```
dpkg -L w3c-markup-validator | grep /bin/
```

will provide a good approximation. If you want to be really precise, here's a regexp that will retain only files in the directories in your `$PATH`.

```
dpkg -L bash | grep -E "^${PATH//:/\/|^}\$"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dpkg -L w3c-markup-validator
```

More generically, dpkg -L [packagename]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out beforehand you can search at packages.ubuntu.com as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use synaptic, then you can right click on the package, click properties and see installed files.
Any files installed under /usr/bin or similar locations would be commands.